# Was bedeutet „erhoben“ hier im Kontext?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Für Beiträge, die wegen Verstoßes des Arbeitgebers gegen die Meldepflicht erst nach Fälligkeit erhoben werden, kann der Träger der Insolvenzsicherung einen Säumniszuschlag erheben.

Bedeutet der obige Satz: Wenn die Beiträge erst nach Fälligkeit verlangt werden, kann der Träger Säumniszuschlag verlangen?

Aber wenn ein Institut selbst die Beiträge zu spät verlangt, warum muss der Arbeitgeber dafür mehr bezahlen? Wo wäre mein Denkfehler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Erheben* wird hier tatsächlich im Sinne von "verlangen", "fordern" verwendet.

*Erheben* ist in seiner juristischen Bedeutung allerdings um eine Nuance anders als die beiden anderen genannten Verben: Wird etwas "erhoben", ist die Forderung bereits rechtlich (z.B. Gesetz oder Vertrag) gesichert und kann nicht verhandelt werden (was bei einer puren "Forderung" durchaus möglich ist). Steuern und amtliche Gebühren z.B. werden normalerweise *erhoben* und nicht *gefordert*.

Im speziellen Fall geht es darum, dass der Arbeitgeber eine Frist versäumt hat, in der er einen bestimmten Sachverhalt hätte melden müssen. Dadurch war die Versicherung nicht in der Lage, Beiträge zu erheben (sic), die ansonsten früher fällig geworden wären - und dafür kann sie Säumniszuschläge erheben (da sie bei einer rechtzeitigen Meldung die Beiträge früher in Rechnung gestellt hätte).

Ein ähnliches Beispiel wäre die verspätete Meldung von Einkünften beim Finanzamt - Wenn dir 2023 plötzlich einfällt, dass du in 2020 10 Millionen mehr verdient hast (warum passiert mir so was eigentlich nie?), als du in deiner Steuererklärung angegeben hast, wird das Finanzamt dir für die Steuern, die 2020 mehr fällig gewesen *wären*, Säumniszuschläge für die Zeit von 2020-23 "erheben" (und natürlich die fälligen Steuern auf die 10M nachfordern).

Answer (score 0):

Wenn eine Information erhoben wird, wird diese erfasst, also in irgendeiner Form dokumentiert.

Ich würde es hier an dieser Stelle aber eher mit gemeldet gleichsetzen wollen.

(Leider kann ich hier juristisch nicht weiterhelfen.)

Comment: Willkommen bei *German Language*! Das Verb *erhoben* bezieht sich im Beispielsatz allerdings auf *Beiträge*, die zugrunde liegende Information ist in *Meldepflicht* versteckt.